# Movie not loaded

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm using Facebook's `Open Graph Protocol` to publish a flash movie from URL, but when I press the play button the movie doesn't load.

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="song's name">
  <meta property="og:type" content="song">
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="song's name">
  <meta property="og:description" content="song's name">
  <meta property="og:image" content="my_img.jpg">      
  <meta property="og:url"   content="my_url">  
  <meta name="medium"         content="video">            
  <meta property="og:video" content="http://my_flas_video.swf"> 
  <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://my_flas_video.swf">       
  <meta property="og:video:height" content="150">
  <meta property="og:video:width" content="150">
  <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">      
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="my_appid"> 
  <meta property="fb:admins" content="my_admin">
```

Any idea?